# Syntax for survival analysis with late-entry

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I am trying to fit a survival model with left-truncated data using the `survival` package however I am unsure of the correct syntax.

Let's say we are measuring the effect of age at when hired (`age`) and job type (`parttime`) on duration of employment of doctors in public health clinics. Whether the doctor quit or was censored is indicated by the `censor` variable (0 for quittting, 1 for censoring). This behaviour was measured in an 18-month window. Time to either quit or censoring is indicated by two variables, `entry` (start time) and `exit`(stop time) indicating how long, in years, the doctor was employed at the clinic. If doctors commenced employment after the window 'opened' their `entry` time is set to 0. If they commenced employment prior to the window 'opening' their `entry` time represents how long they had already been employed in that position when the window 'opened', and their `exit` time is how long from when they were initially hired they either quit or were censored by the window 'closing'. We also postulate a two-way interaction between `age` and duration of employment (`exit`).

This is the toy data set. It is much smaller than a normal dataset would be, so the estimates themselves are not as important as whether the syntax and variables included (using the `survival` package in R) are correct, given the structure of the data. The toy data has the exact same structure as a dataset discussed in Chapter 15 of Singer and Willet's *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis*. I have tried to match the results they report, without success. There is not a lot of explicit information online how to conduct survival analyses on left-truncated data in R, and the website that provides code for the book ([here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/examples/alda/)) does not provide R code for the chapter in question. The methods for modeling time-varying covariates and interaction effects are quite complex in R and I just wonder if I am missing something important.

Here is the toy data

```
id <- 1:40
entry <- c(2.3,2.5,2.5,1.2,3.5,3.1,2.5,2.5,1.5,2.5,1.4,1.6,3.5,1.5,2.5,2.5,3.5,2.5,2.5,0.5,rep(0,20))
exit <- c(5.0,5.2,5.2,3.9,4.0,3.6,4.0,3.0,4.2,4.0,2.9,4.3,6.2,4.2,3.0,3.9,4.1,4.0,3.0,2.0,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.9,1.7,1.1,0.2,2.2,0.8,1.9,1.2,2.3,2.2,0.2,1.7,1.0,0.6,0.2,1.1,1.3)
censor <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,rep(1,20))
parttime <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
age <- c(34,28,29,38,33,33,32,28,40,30,29,34,31,33,28,29,29,31,29,29,30,37,33,38,34,37,37,40,29,38 ,49,32,30,27,35,34,35,30,35,34)

doctors <- data.frame(id,entry,exit,censor,parttime,age)
```

Now for the model.

```
coxph(Surv(entry, exit, 1-censor) ~ parttime + age + age:exit, data = doctors)
```

Is this the correct way to specify the model given the structure of the data and what we want to know? An answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141390/which-model-to-use-for-survival-analysis-when-there-are-different-times-of-entry/143693#143693) suggests it is correct, but I am not sure whether, for example, the interaction variable is correctly specified.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, it's not until I post a question about a problem on SO that I work out how to do it myself. If there is an interaction with time predictor we need to convert the dataset into a count process, person period format (i.e. a long form). This is because each participant needs an interval that tracks their status with respect to the event *for every time point that the event occurred to anyone else in the data set*, up to the point when they exited the study.

First let's make an event variable

```
doctors$event <- 1 - doctors$censor
```

Before we run the cox model we need to use the `survSplit` function in the `survival` package. To do this we need to make a vector of all the time points when an event occurred

```
cutPoints <- order(unique(doctors$exit[doctors$event == 1]))
```

Now we can pass this into the `survSplit` function to create a new dataset...

```
docNew <- survSplit(Surv(entry, exit, event)~.,
                   data = doctors,
                   cut = cutPoints,
                   end = "exit")
```

... which we then run our model on

```
coxph(Surv(entry,exit,event) ~ parttime + age + age:exit, data = docNew)
```

Voila!